# How to change NSURLConnection to NSURLSession in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

I am new in iOS.And I got the error of IPv6 while submitting app to Apple Store. My code is like this

```
-(void)serverconnection{


    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<Method Name xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<UserId>%@</UserId>"
                             "</Method Name>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",userid];




    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL/webservice.asmx?op=MethodName"];
    // NSURLRequest *myNSURequestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/MethodName" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionObj=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionObj);
    if(myNSUConnectionObj)
    {

        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataFromServer=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    [myNSMDataFromServer setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [myNSMDataFromServer appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSXMLParser *myNSXMLParserObj=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:myNSMDataFromServer];
    myNSXMLParserObj.delegate=self;
    [myNSXMLParserObj parse];
    NSLog(@"%@",myNSXMLParserObj.parserError);
    NSLog(@"DataArray: %@",myDataNSMArray);

    Keyarry=[responsedict valueForKey:@"Key"];
    NSLog(@"Assign Count =%@",Keyarry);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Keyarry objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"String value =%@",string);
    ibtassigncountlbl.text =string;

  }

#pragma mark - NSXMLParsing Delegate

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"FillBlocksNew"])
    {
        myDataClassObj=[[mydata alloc]init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    myMutableStringObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObj);
    NSData *data = [myMutableStringObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedict);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"DataArray: %@",myDataNSMArray);
}
```

My question is what delegate use for `didFinishLoading` in `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`.

When I used this delegate below:

`- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn { }`

it shows me error. I need to change from `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` to `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` as suggested by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection method is IPv6 compatible. No need to change it to support IPv6. I think the problem lies in your URL. Somewhere in your application, you might have used hardcoded IPv4 address like (w.x.y.z). Remove such address with proper domain names and application will get pass.

Also you should use the latest Rachability classes.

Comment: How to check URL Address and version of Rachability

Comment: Check in your code where you are creating URLs. Are you using hardcoded IP address like 180.170.160.150? If yes, remove it with proper domain names like hostname.api.com. For reachability download latest reachability. They are IPv6 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `delegate` method are used to create connection between two classes so when you request a `url` ussing `NSURLRequest` it makes connection to `delegate` methods of `NSURLConnection` class which processes the particular requested `url` at a time and responds wisely.

Whereas `NSURLConnection` has two methods that signal that a request has finished (NSURLConnectionDataDelegate -`connectionDidFinishLoading`: and NSURLConnectionDelegate -connection:`didFailWithError`:). Both method signals the completion of particular request.

Now there is nothing wrong using  `NSURLConnection` you just need to make sure about your `URL` and using `delegate` method in a proper way see below.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [webData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    if(!webData){
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response = %@",returnString);
}
```